# Explicit Light Sampling

Tags: graphics

I have written a path tracer in OpenCL.  It works great, but it's slow to converge, particularly for small lights.  In passing, I had heard about explicit light sampling, which vastly speeds this up.

The main problem is I don't understand how it works.  I have seen it implemented as adding the standard Phong model to the material's color each iteration (for example, [GLSL Path Tracer](http://madebyevan.com/webgl-path-tracing/)).  I have also seen it added in only as the final leg of a path.

Can someone explain how explicit light sampling works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that both methods exist.  See:

- http://graphics.ucsd.edu/~iman/BDPT/ (path tracing with next event estimate)
  Direct Lighting Method:
- Peter Shirley and Wang : Direct Lighting Calculation by Monte Carlo Integration

Answer (score 1):

Normal path tracing calculates irradiance by firing rays randomly in surface normal oriented hemisphere. this means that when you have small light sources, probability to hit this light source randomly is very low. to avoid this problem, you must split integration procedure in two parts:

1. direct light integration
2. indirect light integration.

But here is a question: How can i determine which direction will hit light directly?
There are some techniques to do this. One of them is to choose directions in solid angles for all lights and check shadow rays, so you will determine light contribution and visibility.

After that you have calculated direct lighting.
Light coming from rest of the hemisphere is actually indirect lighting.